# Nginx permanent permissions fix

Tags: permissions, apache2, nginx

I’m having a little trouble with permissions in /var/www/html directory. The main problem is - whenever I create new file I needed to give 777 permission, to escape 403 forbidden error. Is there a permanent fix for all files and subdirectories in /var/www/html directory.

I really need your help, so hope you know the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a heads up, it is more secure to grant the lowest possible permissions required. NGINX normally uses the user www-data, in future you can resolve the 403 errors using `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html` and `sudo chmod -R 550 /var/www/html`. This will grant the user and group www-data read and execute access to the web directory. Note the `-R` switch will apply the permissions to the folder and all files and folders within it, so make sure the directory is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid having to always set the permissions manually you can use the `setfacl` command to ensure that future folders and files will get the default file access control set by you.

The steps include:

1. Change the current setup:

   ```
   sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
   ```
2. Add yourself to that group:

   ```
   sudo useradd www-data $USER
   ```

   - Logout and log back in to have this take effect or reboot if it doesn't
3. Set the default facl (File Access Control List)

   ```
   sudo setfacl -d -R -m u:www-data:rwx,g:www-data:r-x,o::r-x /var/www/html
   ```

   - Do `sudo getfacl /var/www/html` to see the changes

Note: This will set the default permissions to `755`

Answer (score 0):

Which user owns the files? If it's anything but www-data (or what ever value is set for `user` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`) you need to either give permissions to all users, which is the last digit of the [octal permissions](http://www.nersc.gov/users/storage-and-file-systems/unix-file-permissions/), or change the owner of the files/folders.

To change the owner to www-data do: `chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html/`.

If you don't want to change the owner you could do `chmod 664 -R /var/www/html/`.
The 4 at the end means that all users can read the file/folder and so Nginx will be able to display the files but not edit.